# How to define columns similar to QML TableViewColumn?

Tags: c++, qt, mvvm, qml, qtableview

I worked with MVVM in WPF and now trying to use Qt. Qt View Model concept is clear to me (I hope). Still I tried to use c# style and make Qt "observable colection", which is actually a list with a single role defined - a pointer to an object:

```
class ObjectsListModel : public QAbstractListModel {
Q_OBJECT
public:
    enum RoleNames {
        ObjectRole = Qt::UserRole + 1
    };

... 

    QList<QObject*> data_;
};
```

Therefore 1st question: is there already a standard implementation for this?

Then I defined a class with 2 properties:

```
class HumanModel : public QObject
{
Q_OBJECT
public:
Q_PROPERTY(QString name READ getName WRITE setName NOTIFY nameChanged);
Q_PROPERTY(QString nickname READ getNickname WRITE setNickname NOTIFY nicknameChanged);
...
```

Then inside QML I created a tableview:

```
TableView {     
    model: my_observable_collection
    TableViewColumn { role: "name"; title: "Name"; width: 50; }
    TableViewColumn { role: "nickname"; title: "Nickname"; width: 50; }
```

It worked very well, all notifications, changing of list contents, etc., perfect.

Now I would like to use QTableView (non-QML, simple Qt UI) using the same list model and HumanModel. Is it possible (without creating new "table"-viewmodel wich duplicates all properties of HumanModel)?

Comment: Yes. (Yet I don't know if this answer is sufficient)

Comment: Have you read the documentation and tried?

Comment: Well, yes, I read specs and didnt find a proprer way to use my model (which works well in QML) in Qt with QTableView.